# How can I write a hook to activate when any emacs frame is raised/focused?

Tags: emacs, elisp, frames

Under Win32, each emacs frame shows up as a different window when Alt-tabbing, which makes sense. However, when I select my main editing window, I'd also like my speedbar frame to auto-raise along with it.

Writing a function to raise all frames (or even all currently NOT visible frames) is relatively trivial, but I can't figure out hook to use, or indeed if there's even a hook that's possible to use at all.

So, if I click or alt-tab to any of my emacs frames, a hook should be run to call my function that raises ALL frames. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem that GNU emacs has any such functionality.

Xemacs has select-frame-hook and map-frame-hook. There is also the variable auto-raise-frame, but, not in GNU emacs.

See http://www.xemacs.org/Documentation/beta/html/lispref_40.html#SEC526 for some ideas if you feel like improving emacs.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can find in GNU Emacs is the `switch-frame` event, but it's only generated when a different Emacs frame is focused, not when you switch to a non-Emacs window and then back to the same frame.

This is the sort of things that a good enough window manager should do, with a bit of cooperation from Emacs (for example using window titles to figure out what the speedbar frame is).

Under Windows, you should be able to use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)'s [WinWaitActive](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWaitActive.htm) command.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hook you can use with.

```
server-visit-hook is a variable defined in `server.el'.
Original value was nil

Documentation:
Hook run when visiting a file for the Emacs server.

You can customize this variable.
```

When you find a file with Emacs server or emacsclient, 
this hook will invoked. you can use this hook to do something need.